# Why is git asking for passwords to public repos added as submoules but not while cloning directly

Tags: git

I'm wondering why using `git clone` on public repo works fine with any link but not when the exact same link is used in `.gitmodules`. I do know that changing `.gitmodules` `https` URL to `git@` "solves" this issue but there are projects with dozens of public submodules.

Comment: 1. Can you please show an example of such a public repo with submodules? 2. You can replace any amount of URLs on the fly using `url…insteadOf`.

Comment: Sure:https://github.com/espressif/connectedhomeip/blob/4f7669b052b16bd054227376e1bbadac85419793/.gitmodules

Comment: Repository https://github.com/Qorvo/qpg-connectedhomeip is private so Git asks for password. Using `git@github.com:Qorvo/qpg-connectedhomeip.git` doesn't help

Comment: Oh, you are right they must have renamed it to https://github.com/Qorvo/QMatter

Comment: Update `.gitmodules`.